# Arcpy.Exists Fails On Existing Layers

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, mxd

I am running into an issue where the `arcpy.Exists()` function returns a `false` for a known good layer in the python interactive window.  We are using a map document template for the layers set up in the Table of Contents.

I usually would drag the layer from the Table Of Contents into the interactive window so it shows like `r'Work Layers\Replacement Tree'` since it is part of a group in the Table of Contents.  If I manually add in the data instead of use a template and resource the layers, the `arcpy.Exists()` function works and returns `true`, but on occasion, it will return a `false`.

When it returns `false`, I can check the layer's source, navigate to the location and specified feature class, and see that it is there.  I can add it in manually and run it, too.

For some reason, it seems using an existing map document as a template and resourcing the Table of Contents breaks this on occasion.  The code I am using is a bit more complex than the `arcpy.Exists()`, but I have narrowed it down to that being the issue.  My code throws an exception saying a particular layer doesn't exist so that is the easiest way to troubleshoot.

I have even gone as far as to drag multiple layers from the Table Of Contents into a list in the interactive window and iterate over it with `arcpy.Exists()` to the same result of `false`.

I can set the workspace to the file geodatabase we're using and the using the feature class name (ie. `layer = 'Replacement Tree'`) links to the correct feature class.

Is there a bug or a disconnect somewhere when using a map document as a template and resourcing the data from the Table of Contents to the python interactive window so that layers (which show up on the data frame, too!) aren't connected as if they were added in manually?

Also posted to [GeoNet..](https://geonet.esri.com/message/460988#460988)

**Update From GeoNet**

Following a suggestion to check the dataSource of each of the layers in my list, I tried a little different code.

I ended up with this copied from the interactive window.. Formatting is a little weird from the copy/paste.

```
>>> for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*Replace*"):
...     print lyr.dataSource
...    
C:\***\*****\F_Geodatabase\*****.gdb\ReplacementTree
>>> for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*Replace*"):
...     print lyr.dataSource
...     print arcpy.Exists(lyr)
...    
C:\***\*****\F_Geodatabase\*****.gdb\ReplacementTree
False
>>>
```

Now from there, I hit *add data* and added in the same feature class, from the same geodatabase and re-ran the above script to get:

```
>>> for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*Replace*"):
...     print lyr.dataSource
...     print arcpy.Exists(lyr)
...    
C:\***\*****\F_Geodatabase\*****.gdb\ReplacementTree
False
C:\***\*****\F_Geodatabase\*****.gdb\ReplacementTree <--Put in here by hitting add data button (same file)
True
>>>
```

So, I don't exactly get why two TOC items, both sourced to the same feature class, shows as one existing and one not.  The only difference is that one (that doesn't exist) was re-sourced via a python script, while the other (that exists) was added manually.

Comment: It is not legal to have spaces in a table name (it's bad practice with *any* path, but not possible in tables).  You may not be distinguishing between layer name (which as pure text, does not have any restrictions) and source table for that layer.

Comment: No, my major issue is that I can mimic what is already in the template (layer name and table name as the source) table of contents by adding data and changing the names, etc, and it shows up fine in the python interactive window.  On occasions like today, those re-sourced items in the TOC show as they don't exist in the interactive window for some reason.  I don't think it is a naming issue, more of a disconnect between the TOC and interactive window on re-sourced items.